# Configure nginx to run Jitsi on Debian 10

Tags: nginx, debian, jitsi, debian-buster, jitsi-meet

I am running an out of the box Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) with nginx and this nginx config file:

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.abc.de**

```
server {
  server_name example.abc.de;
  root /var/www/example.abc.de/;
  index index.html;

  listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.abc.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.abc.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = example.abc.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  server_name example.abc.de;
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Now I follow step by step the install tutorial at:
https://jitsi.org/downloads/ubuntu-debian-installations-instructions/

- `wget -qO - https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi-key.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -`
- `sh -c "echo 'deb https://download.jitsi.org stable/' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi-stable.list"`
- `apt-get -y update`
- `apt-get -y install jitsi-meet`

After than I open https://example.abc.de in my web browser and all I see is the content of the `/var/www/example.abc.de/index.html` file. And that makes sense because the nginx configuration file hasn't changed.

No documentation I can find on https://jitsi.org gives me any additional information. They all say `apt-get -y install jitsi-meet` and fire up the URL in your browser afterwards.

What is the documentation missing? What do I have to configure to make it happen that I can open the URL in the browser to the the Jitsi system?

Comment: I asked the same question here: https://community.jitsi.org/t/installation-tutorial-doesnt-work-on-a-vanilla-debian-10/25898 and will add an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **The current Debian packages don't work with Debian 10.**

I posted the same question on a Jitsi board:
https://community.jitsi.org/t/installation-tutorial-doesnt-work-on-a-vanilla-debian-10/25898

The answer was that the current Debian package needs Java 8 but Debian 10 ships with Java 11. For those who are willing to spend the time they can downgrade to Java 8.

Side note: I might say that it is quite disappointing that the Jitsi community publishes a Debian package and puts it in there own install how-to which does not work with the current stable version von Debian.